How to concatenate in Django annotate()
I want to concatenate a string variable with one of my fields, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong
I tried this, where prefix is a string and filename_mask is a field in the table
 plots = (
            PlotDefinitions.objects.filter(is_active=True)
            .annotate(
                filename=Concat(Value(prefix), 'filename_mask')
            )
            .values('name', 'description', 'filename')
        )

I get the error Expression contains mixed types: CharField, TextField. You must set output_field. even though I'm concatenating 2 String type.
So I added output_field
 plots = (
            PlotDefinitions.objects.filter(is_active=True)
            .annotate(
                filename=Concat(Value(prefix), 'filename_mask', output_field=CharField())
            )
            .values('name', 'description', 'filename')
        )

but this gives me the error  "'CharField' object has no attribute 'get_internal_type'"

Although you aren't showing the import, the model field CharField does have a get_internal_type method so like the answer to the duplicate mentions I guess you're importing the form field instead of the model field. If not, please [edit] and provide a proper [mre]
